# Does anyone know of a uniruled hypersurface over $ \mathbb{C} $, which is not rationally connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Does anyone know of any projective, hypersurfaces $ Z $ which are uniruled, but not rationally connected such that $ Z $ is not an $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}} $ bundle over another variety.  Note that I am not requiring that the hypersurface be smooth or even normal.

Comment: Too easy: any variety is birational to a hypersurface (use generic projections). So your question is whether there exists a uniruled variety which is not rationally connected, and of course the answer is yes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the most important part.  Namely, that the hypersurface must be general.  I believe, that this rules out Walter's example.

Comment: Then there are no examples I think. If $X$ is general, it is smooth, and if it is in addition uniruled, it must be Fano, hence rationally connected (by Bend and break).

Comment: Sorry again, I believe that I used the term general to mean that the hypersurface is not an $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}} $ bundle over another variety.  In this case the hypersurface $ Z(\langle x_{0}x_{1}x_{2}-x_{3}^{3} \rangle) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{3}_{\mathbb{C}} $ is singular, and uniruled.  However, it is rational.  I do not know of an example of a hypersurface which is not an $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}} $ bundle that is uniruled but not rationally connected.  Sorry about the confusion.